# Images align left not working with li tag in html and css

Tags: html, css

I am making an image slider with jquery and for that purpose I am trying to align images in one line with li tag using css but it's not happening the way I want.

I want to slide from left to right when the first image reach in the middle then the second image comes in, this Image shows exactly what I want.

[image]

```
<div id="divFrame">
        <ul id="ulId">
            <li class="service-list"><img src="images/a.jpe"></img></li>
            <li class="service-list"><img src="images/b.jpe"></img></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
#divFrame
{
width: 311px;
height: 333px;
background-color: gray;
position: relative; 
margin-left: 20%;
overflow: hidden;
}


img{
float: left;
}

.liClass {
list-style-type: none;
margin-left:0px;
padding-left:0px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

if I remove the overflow hidden property from divFrame and decrease the divFrame  then it shows images like below, and why It's creating weird gap on left and top.

[image]

if I increase the divFrame size more then these two images then it shows like that

[image]

```
<html>

    <head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <html>

    <body>

    <div id="divFrame">
    <ul id="ulId">
        <li class="service-list"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />   
    </li>
        <li class="service-list"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Try `display: inline-block;` for the img CSS rather than floats.

Comment: nop that didn't work

Comment: Is the typo in your `.liClass` just here in the question, or in your actual code? The selector should be `li` or `.service-list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Correct your markup**.

  - there's *no such thing* as an `</img>` tag. IMG tags are self-closing. The proper way to close an img tag is to use `<img src="" />`.
  - Your CSS targets a class titled `.liClass`, but that class is *nowhere* in your posted HTML.

With cleanup, and correction, removing the CSS for the images and *actually* targeting the li items via a class, `display: inline-block;` should correct this issue. Note that I also added `white-space: nowrap;` to the `ul` CSS.

## [jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/q2km5ydj/2/)

<sup>(with corrections)</sup>

Comment: can't I have width of divFrame in pixels for example you make width for divFrame 50% it work in this way but not with 311px ?

Comment: and what about top and left extra spaces they are not gone, how do I remove them

Comment: The width was merely for the fiddle example.. I can't see your entire page. Note **this is an example** to show how it can be done. I can't see your page... I have **no clue** what the rest of the markup looks like.

Comment: the markup is just like yours I just copy and replace it with mine that's it. Any way just difference with 50% and px please explain only this one

Comment: @mohsin surely that's not the case. You **must** have other HTML... a body tag... a head tag... other items on the page.... Your web pages surely doesn't consist of *only* 2 images.

Comment: I am just practicing only slider and only having this code in my file, yes you are right I dafinately have html header and body tags

Comment: I just add all of it up in my question

Comment: StackOverflow is **not** a coding service. Most users here answering questions are merely seeking to assist with problems. This answer, like many, is designed to help you grasp a concept or see how markup/code can be changed to accomplish what you want. It is not, if ever, intended to be a direct copy/paste solution to every problem that may arise. In short, some deductive reasoning with respect to your **own** project is expected, and in most cases required. To put it more bluntly. I'm not going to write your page for you. You'll have to figure out some things yourself.